How to filter elements by multiselect field via relatedTo
I have a "Tasks" section. Each entry in this section has a multiselect "Year" field and a category selection field.
How do I filter by these fields via relatedTo?
I'm trying to do this:
{% set selectedFields = [
    'and',
    {element: category.id, field: 'categoryPrint'},
    {element: [year|integer], field: 'yearField'}
] %}
{{ dump(selectedFields) }}
{% do prints.relatedTo(selectedFields).all() %}

I suspect that the problem is in the yearField field:
{element: [year|integer], field: 'yearField'}

The 'yearField' field is a multiselect. Each menu item does not have its own id and perhaps because of this I cannot filter the items. Can you tell me what to do?

I wrote an in-depth article covering this a few years ago which might be useful reading: https://cld.agency/blog/multi-faceted-filtering-in-craftcms
To more directly answer your question though:
You can only use relatedTo for fetching/filtering by element relationships. A multiselect field is not a relationship to another element, it's just a value stored against the entry. (Relationship fields are entries, assets, categories, and users).
In order to filter by a normal field, you can simply use the field handle as a parameter in a  standard element query - e.g.:
craft.entries.textFieldHandle('some value').all()
...or as an array (each value will be treated as having an implicit "OR" between it):
craft.entries.multiSelectHandle(['optionHandle1', 'optionHandle2']).all()
With this knowledge in hand, it should now become clear that you can combine your relatedTo() method to simultaneously filter by a category relationship and a multiselect field like this:
{% set entries = craft.entries.yearField(arrayOfYears).relatedTo(category.id).all() %}

(the yearField and relatedTo parameters will be joined with an implicit "AND" between them).
